# "The git repository at '/home/upulie/Desktop' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled"

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

`The git repository at '/home/upulie/Desktop' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled`

Source: Git(Extension)

This warning comes up in the corner in VS Code when opening up a React project.
I can't understand why it happens as I don't have any .git file inside my '/home/upulie/Desktop' neither anywhere inside it.

(The project I'm trying to open is inside a folder in Desktop)

Why does this happen and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: can you do a `ls -a` and check if there are any git related files?

Comment: I couldn't use the -a flag before. There was a .git folder in my Desktop.Thanks .

Answer (score 8):

Check first if your have a `/home/upulie/Desktop/.git/` folder.

If so, you should rename (or even delete) it: Desktop should not, in its entirety, be a Git repository.
Only a subfolder representing a project should have a Git repository in it.

Answer (score 1):

FOR WINDOWS USER ONLY:

This happens when you execute the "git init" command inside of your user folder. To solve that I recommend follow this, if you're working on a Windows computer:

Enable viewing “hidden items” in your computer’s file explorer. First open the file explorer to C:\Users<username>, click on the View tab, and select the “Hidden Items” checkbox. Delete the .git folder and everything should work fine again.